# Render a different page based on login using yii framework

Tags: php, yii, authentication

I would like the home page rendered depend on the user role login.

Currently I have this in the protected/controllers/break;SiteController.php but it redirects to another page.

```
protected function roleBasedHomePage() {
     $roles = Yii::app()->user->getState('roles'); //however you define your role, have the value output to this variable
    switch($role) {
        case 'admin':
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/page',array('view'=>$roles.'homepage')));
        break;
        case 'b':
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/page',array('view'=>$roles.'homepage')));
        break;
        case 'guest':
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/page',array('view'=>'homepage')));
        break;
        //etc..
    }

 public function actionLogin()
{

    $model = new LoginForm();

    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model, array('username', 'password', 'verify_code'));
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        if ($model->validate(array('username', 'password', 'verify_code')) && $model->login()) {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Welcome ' . app()->user->name);
           // $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
           $this->roleBasedHomePage();
        }
    }

    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));

}
}
```

This works if I want to redirect the page but I want the home page url to be the same and the content to change depending on 'roles'.

e.g. if the user is 'admin' then I want 'adminhome' rendered

I'm guessing the function below has something to do with it?

```
 public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->render('index');


}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this easily. first create a view for every role. then redirect every one to your home page after login, but check their role and depending on that, "renderPartial()" the view for that role. like:

```
switch($role){
   case 'admin' :
      $this->renderPartial('application.views.site._admin');    // view for admin
      break;
   case 'superUser':
      $this->renderPartial('application.views.site._superUser');// view for super user
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Ajax as an option, if what you want to change is the content of the page but keep the same footer and header.

For instance:

1- Create three different views, admin.php, b.php and guest.php.

2- In your controller create three different methods: renderAdmin(), renderB() and renderGuest(). Each one will render the corresponding view.

3- In the same controller define the Access rules for the specific role and methods, so an Ajax call from an invalid user will not be allowed (in case someone sees your code and tries to invoke the method based in the Ajax URL where you send the post to). This because in the default header that you use in your 'index.php' you will assign the JS script which calls the specific method, the method will return the view and thats what you render on the 'main' content div.

4- In the login() you call the index method.

5- In the index method you render the 'index' view and pass the path to the specific JS script which calls the 'adminview', for instance.

You could also use [Update content in AJAX with renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial/)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Change your index action in the controller to something like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $roles = Yii::app()->user->getState('roles');

    $view = $this->getViewForRole($roles); // you have to implement this function
    $this->render($view . '_index');
}
```

Create the view files in the views folder: admin_index.php, customer_index.php etc.